# Symfony 4, custom serializer really slow

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, serialization

I upgraded from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4.

Since v4.2 setCallbacks() and setCircularReferenceHandler() are deprecated so I replaced them by passing context to ObjectNormalizer.

Actually this is working BUT when I have a lot of entity (hundreds or thousands) to serialize it takes more than 30 seconds and obviously throws a timed-out.

For example, in 3.4 it takes 7 seconds to serialize 1444 objects, it takes +30 seconds in 4.4.

Before:

```
class MyEntitySerializer extends Serializer
{
    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer, JsonEncoder $encoder)
    {
        $dateCallback = function ($dateTime) {
            return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
                ? date_format($dateTime,'d/m/Y')
                : null;
        };
         $normalizer->setCallbacks([
            'debut' => $dateCallback,
            'fin' => $dateCallback,
            'demandeDate' => $dateCallback,
            'dateCreation' => $dateCallback,
        ]);

        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
            if ($object instanceof Affaire) {
                return $object->getCode();
            } elseif ($object instanceof ComplementAffaire) {
                return $object->getDescription();
            }

            return $object->getId();
        }); 

        parent::__construct([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
    }
}
```

After:

```
class MyEntitySerializer extends Serializer
{
    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer, JsonEncoder $encoder)
    {
        $dateCallback = function ($dateTime) {
            return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
                ? date_format($dateTime,'d/m/Y')
                : null;
        };

        $defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
                'debut' => $dateCallback,
                'fin' => $dateCallback,
                'demandeDate' => $dateCallback,
                'dateCreation' => $dateCallback,
            ],
            AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object) {
                if ($object instanceof Affaire) {
                    return $object->getCode();
                } elseif ($object instanceof ComplementAffaire) {
                    return $object->getDescription();
                }
                return $object->getId();
            }
        ];

        $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory,null,null,null,null,null,$defaultContext);
        parent::__construct([$normalizer], [$encoder]);
    }
}
```

I injected ClassMetadataFactoryInterface and pass it to ObjectNormalizer, here's what this serializer looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlZqV.png)
There are no CacheClassMetadataFactory. It worked like before (as slow as before).

I tried remove var/cache/ and vendor/ then I did a `composer install`
here's the installed versions:

```
 - Installing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.8.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing squizlabs/php_codesniffer (3.5.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer (v0.6.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing behat/transliterator (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing clue/stream-filter (v1.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (1.10.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/reflection (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/collections (1.6.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/persistence (1.3.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/common (2.13.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.1.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/doctrine-bridge (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing laminas/laminas-eventmanager (3.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing laminas/laminas-code (3.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ocramius/proxy-manager (2.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (v1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/serializer (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/var-exporter (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing http-interop/http-factory-guzzle (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu (2.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu-bundle (v2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy (v1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/promise (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v5.5.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/message (1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/httplug (2.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/discovery (1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/client-common (2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/guzzle6-adapter (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing jean85/pretty-package-versions (1.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sentry/sentry (2.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-core (v4.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sentry/sdk (2.1.0)
  - Installing sentry/sentry-symfony (3.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.4.41): Loading from cache
  - Installing stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.13.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bridge (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug-bundle (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/expression-language (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/string (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/inflector (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.18): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mailer (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bridge (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.12.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (v1.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/orm-pack (v1.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.17.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/intl (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/property-access (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-http (v4.4.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-guard (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-csrf (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/security-bundle (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v3.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-bundle (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/extra-bundle (v3.0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/twig-pack (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/validator (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/asset (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/webpack-encore-bundle (v1.7.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing tecnickcom/tcpdf (6.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/form (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing jms/metadata (2.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing vich/uploader-bundle (1.14.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/translation (v4.4.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing willdurand/js-translation-bundle (3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/data-fixtures (1.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (3.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/maker-bundle (v1.19.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v5.0.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/stopwatch (v5.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/profiler-pack (v1.0.4): Loading from cache
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of this line:

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
```

When you get `ObjectNormalizer` from service container rather than instantiating it yourself, it receives this metadataFactory (it is from a container dump):

```
return $container->privates['serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory'] = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\CacheClassMetadataFactory(
            new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory(
                new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\LoaderChain(
                    [
                        0 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader(
                            ($container->privates['annotations.cached_reader'] ?? $container->getAnnotations_CachedReaderService(
                                ))
                        ),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpArrayAdapter::create(
                ($container->targetDir . '' . '/serialization.php'),
                ($container->privates['cache.serializer'] ?? $container->load('getCache_SerializerService'))
            )
        );
```

It is using cache.

In `vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Resources/config/serializer.xml` you can see the following:

```
        <service id="serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory" class="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory">
            <argument type="service" id="serializer.mapping.chain_loader" />
        </service>

        <service id="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface" alias="serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory" />
...
        <service id="serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory" decorates="serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory" class="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\CacheClassMetadataFactory">
            <argument type="service" id="serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory.inner" />
            <argument type="service" id="serializer.mapping.cache.symfony" />
        </service>
```

Service `serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory` decorates `serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory` which has an alias `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface`.

So you can inject `'@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface'` service to `MyEntitySerializer` and use it to create your `ObjectNormalizer` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my YAML service config file I have 

MyBundle\Util\MyEntitySerializer:
        arguments: ['@serializer.normalizer.object', '@serializer.encoder.json', '@serializer.mapping.factory.cache_class_metadata_factory']


If I put CacheClassMetadataFactory in the third argument in MyEntitySerializer constructor, then I do a cache:clear it tells me :
The service "MyBundle\Util\MyEntitySerializer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory".

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the answer, correct service id is `'Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface'` (you will receive `CacheClassMetadataFactory`) because `'@serializer.mapping.factory.cache_class_metadata_factory'` is a service decorator.

Comment: I just edited my main post, unfortunately it worked as slow as before... :(

Comment: Show the service definition in services.yaml please. I will try to find the problem.
Or just search by this interface (`ClassMetadataFactoryInterface`) in `var` folder. It should appear in `var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml`, something like: 
`<service id="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface" alias="serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory" public="false"/>`

Comment: MyBundle\Util\MyEntitySerializer:
        arguments: ['@serializer.normalizer.object', '@serializer.encoder.json', '@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface']

Comment: I have indeed :    `<service id="Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface" alias="serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory" public="false"/>`
in `cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml`:, what should I do ?
but I don't have cache_class_metadata_factory in this .xml

Comment: Have you updated your `symfony/framework-bundle` package to ^4 version? I've checked your example on 3.4 version and yes, there is no such service (`'serializer.mapping.cache_class_metadata_factory'`). This may be the reason.


Because ^4 version of serializer uses decorator for caching, and ^3 accepts cache in the second constructor argument.

^3.4 version of framework-bundle will not define the required decorators => no cache.

Comment: I have 4.4.10 version for symfony/framework-bundle. What should I search/do?

Comment: It is very strange. Try to do `rm -rf var/cache`. Or maybe you just pulled an updated composer.json but haven't really installed new package versions? Try `composer install`. I see no other variants.

Comment: I tried it, you can see on my main post the installed package versions. Maybe one version is too old or too new.